# What's the point of Airdroid's "Find phone" feature if phone is not on the same network

Tags: lost-phone, push-notifications, airdroid

I started using Airdroid today and was perplexed by how its "Find phone" feature works. As far as I can tell, my web Airdroid and my phone Airdroid are connected only when they are in the same local network.

So if my phone is truly lost and thus not on the same network, I can't get connect to my phone via my web Airdroid. What's the point of the "Find phone" feature then?

Comment: It's certainly possible to misplace your phone within range of your own network. It sounds like it's merely intended for a scenario like that.

Comment: Okay -- so that's the intended use? I'm trying to decide whether Airdroid is a solution to the stolen phone situation, especially since they claim to have "Wipe", "Intruder" modes.

Comment: That does seem odd if it only works over your local network. I can't think of many scenarios where I'd want to wipe my phone when it had simply fallen behind a couch cushion. I've never used Airdroid, though, so maybe there's some kind of configuration for the lost phone functionality that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think airdroid's features is to automatically find airdroid devices on your network. Not to locate the physical device. I could be mistaken as I never used airdroid. But my first thought would be to discover a device that is capable of connecting to for airdroid.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an account with Airdroid and link your phone to that account. It'll then use a 3g/4g connection if WiFi isn't available.

Alternatively, if you're looking to use it as a security feature, if your phone is linked to your Google Account, you can use [Google's Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) to wipe/Find/Lock/Make it Ring remotely.